# What are the conditions for a Foreground service to run indefinitely in Android 8?

Tags: android, service

My main app supports different hardware attachments. It ranges from RFID readers to stepper motors controllers.
Because the app is quite independent and the scenarios where attachments are used is rare, I have decided to remove all the code from the main app and move it to services which are installed on specific devices.
The services used to communicate using the Intents.

Recently the devices running the app were upgraded to Android 8 and I can no longer use a background service as I used to because it's killed after a few moments.

I went through the docs in here: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

It seems I should use the Foreground Service, however when searching for more info about foreground services I have found that it is not a suitable solution for long-running processes (the RFID reading process runs from boot to shutdown).

When developing the first solution a while back I have decided not to use the Bound services as they are far less convenient than just waiting for the incoming intents.

I don't mind at all the notification icon, I actually like it as it will allow us to easily see what's running and what's not when interacting with a device. 
I just don't want to invest time in rebuilding the app and then ending up with something that does not work.

What should I do to make sure that the service will run indefinitely and will not be killed? I will not be able to monitor it from my main app and restart when needed.

Comment: "I have found that it is not a suitable solution for long-running processes" -- what makes you say that? "What should I do to make sure that the service will run indefinitely and will not be killed?" -- build your own custom ROM to power the Android hardware. Otherwise, nothing lasts forever. A foreground service is as close as you will get.

Comment: A google search on "foreground service killed" brings a lot of results which looks like scenarios similar to mine (constantly interacting with external hardware) where authors end up with "I have not found a solution to that".

Comment: Right... but that simply shows that even foreground services have limits. Android, as supplied on off-the-shelf hardware, IMHO is not suitable for your scenario, as it is a consumer OS optimized for consumers and their needs. A customized Android build could work for you, as would various embedded Linux options, as then you have greater control over things like process lifetime.